# Includepdf pages with page numbering of new document and remove blank page after section heading

Tags: graphics, page-numbering, pdfpages

I am a beginner to LaTeX and I have a few problems with the `pdfpages` package. I have to include certain pages from another file (compile them into a final report). I use the `\includepdf{pages=3-5}{name.pdf}` command but this creates two problems for me:

1. The numbers are 3,4,5 which do not match the pages of my report (they should start from 5 onwards). Is there a command to do so?
2. I have a section after which I include the pdf pages. This creates a page with solely the section name and the pdf inclusion starts from the next page. I tried using `\includegraphics` but that cuts off some of the content of the pdf. Is there a better way too?

#### Edit: solution for the page numbers

Ok, I found a solution which is so simple I am stupid for not reading about it first. I just had to add `pagecommand={}` in the options for the `\includepdf` command. This created a problem of having two page numbers on each page which I solved by removing the page numbers of the included document. The problem of the blank page is still there so if anyone has a solution, I would be grateful.

#### Edit2: MWE:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{enumerate,a4wide,graphicx,pdfpages} 
\title{Final Report} 

\begin{document} 
\section{Workplan} 
\includepdf[pages=3-5,pagecommand={}]{Workplan.pdf} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: \documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{enumerate,a4wide,graphicx,pdfpages}
\title{Final Report}
\begin{document}

\section{Workplan}
 \includepdf[pages=3-5,pagecommand={}]{Workplan.pdf}
\end{document}

Comment: You might find [my answer here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/160646/include-multiple-pdf-pages-on-single-sheet/160677#160677) includes something useful.

Answer (score 4):

The page numbering problem you have already solved. It remains the first page with the section title. You could use `\includegraphics[page=3]{Workplan.pdf}`, appropriately scaled, after `\section`. But because of the section, there is less space on the first page, thus the page probably needs to be scaled down.

An alternative is again using `pagecommand`:

```
\begin{document}
\includepdf[
  pages=3,
  pagecommand={\section{Workplan}},
]{Workplan}
\includepdf[
  page=4-5,
  pagecommand={},
]{Workplan}
\end{document}
```

Depending on the margin settings and the first page of `Workplan.pdf` the section title may collide with stuff of the embedded page.

If `Workplan.pdf` is also generated by LaTeX, perhaps including/inputting the TeX
source might also be an option.

Comment: Since no particular solution was perfect, I went with making the section heading bold and in the middle of the page and then starting the content from the next page. Thanks for all your help!