# Include multiple pdf pages on single sheet

Tags: graphics, titlesec, pdfpages

I would like to include multiple pages from a pdf document on a single page im my document.
`\includepdf` can do that using the 'nup' option.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\begin{document}

\chapter{includepdf}
\includepdf[pages={1-4},nup=2x2,pagecommand={\thispagestyle{fancy}}]{numbered_pages.pdf}
\includepdf[pages={1-4},nup=1x2,pagecommand={\thispagestyle{fancy}},angle=90]{numbered_pages.pdf}

\end{document}
```

However,

1. The 2x2 pages are not displayed on the `\chapter`-page
2. On a regular page my header and footer are not respected, and
3. The order should be 2-1-4-3 on two consecutive 1x2 pages, so that I can turn my printed document after binding 90 deg clockwise.

> **Responding to @Werner's request, I added the following code that produces roughly what I have in mind, using `\includegraphics`.**

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\chapter{Desired Output}
\centering\null\hfill
\includegraphics[page=1,width=.35\linewidth,height=.4\textheight,keepaspectratio]{numbered_pages}
\hfill
\includegraphics[page=2,width=.35\linewidth,height=.4\textheight,keepaspectratio]{numbered_pages}
\hfill\null\vfill\null\hfill
\includegraphics[page=3,width=.35\linewidth,height=.4\textheight,keepaspectratio]{numbered_pages}
\hfill
\includegraphics[page=4,width=.35\linewidth,height=.4\textheight,keepaspectratio]{numbered_pages}
\hfill\null\clearpage

\null\vfill\noindent
\includegraphics[page=5,width=.48\linewidth,height=.45\textheight,keepaspectratio]{numbered_pages}
\hfill
\includegraphics[page=6,width=.48\linewidth,height=.45\textheight,keepaspectratio]{numbered_pages}
\vfill
\includegraphics[page=7,width=.48\linewidth,height=.45\textheight,keepaspectratio]{numbered_pages}
\hfill
\includegraphics[page=8,width=.48\linewidth,height=.45\textheight,keepaspectratio]{numbered_pages}
\vfill\null

\noindent
\includegraphics[page=2,width=.45\textheight,angle=90]{numbered_pages}
\vfill
\includegraphics[page=1,width=.45\textheight,angle=90]{numbered_pages}
\includegraphics[page=4,width=.45\textheight,angle=90]{numbered_pages}
\vfill
\includegraphics[page=3,width=.45\textheight,angle=90]{numbered_pages}

\end{document}
```

[image]

This serves as an illustration, but has the following flaws

- If the `\chapter` page is modified with `titlesec`, the code does not adapt itself to it
- If the total number of pages is not a multiple of 4, the last pages are not typeset as they were otherwise
- On 1x2 pages, if a larger amount of pages is to be included, the pages need to be included individually by 2,1,4,3,6,5,8... (i.e. 4n-2,4n-3,4n,4n-1), can't a loop do that for me?

I do not have any preference for either `\includepdf` or `\includegraphics`. All I want to show on these pages are header, footer and the included pages.

**How would I need to define `\mycommand` such that the listed shortcomings are addressed and that**

```
\begin{document}

\chapter{Desired Output}
\mycommand[pages={1-8},nup=2x2]{numbered_pages.pdf}
\mycommand[pages={1-4},nup=1x2,]{numbered_pages.pdf}

\end{document}
```

**yields my desired output as depicted above?**

Comment: Could you clarify (3) with a picture? Also, will there be other contents on the page other than the header/footer?

Comment: @Werner - If the pdf-pages are not shown on a `\chapter` page, there will be only header and footer

Comment: The trouble is you are now asking for a command which will fit 4 images into an unknown area since you want to be able to make arbitrary changes to the styling of the chapter title. That greatly increases the complexity of what would be involved. Moreover, it isn't clear whether there is even any guarantee that you will be using `titlesec` or whether that is just a possibility or, if you do, what changes you will make with it. Moreover, requiring that answers adhere to the given syntax is extremely restrictive. As is ruling out a specially adapted form of `\chapter`.

Comment: By the way, none of the solutions suggested require the number of pages to be a multiple of 4 as far as I can tell.

Comment: The third of your 'shortcomings' can be dealt with using the `landscape` option for `\includepdf`. I've edited my answer to use this option. The second is not a problem as far as I can tell. If I ask for 5 pages to be included, I get 5 pages included. Perhaps you could add an example of the problem you're seeing as I can't reproduce it here. That leaves the first, which I don't think would be at all easy to solve given that you might change the page layout in arbitrary ways. It would not be hard to write a `\newcommand` *if* you didn't require it to work straight after `\chapter`.

Comment: `\includepdf` always starts a new page so there is no way to make this work with `pdfpages`. `pgfpages` is a bit different but designed to work with pages created in the same document. That leaves `\includegraphics` but then you need to start thinking about writing yourself a package, I think, as you won't be able to leverage the facilities of `pdfpages`.

Comment: (1) Just assume it is guaranteed that `titlesec` is used. Is there no way to measure the reduced '`\textheight`' on `\chapter` pages? (2) That's right, but my illustration example requires a multiple of 4 - I just meant to say that I cannot do it myself and therefore post this question. (3) Nice. (4) Also nice, then I learned sth. about `\includepdf`

Comment: Could you post the code you are using to tailor the `\chapter` command? Re. (1): `textheight` is not reduced on the first page of chapters. They typically use the `plain` pagestyle so header and footer is varied but not their heights. The main problem, though, is that there is no easy and reliable way to tell `pdfpages` to use different settings for the first 4 pages it includes. Re. (2): Oh, OK. Fair enough. Re. (3-4): `pdfpages` is pretty nice, I think, as is `pgfpages` (for different cases).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

---

## For Previous Readers

---

*If reading this answer for the first time, you will be none the wiser for reading the next paragraph and may safely skip to the Introduction below.*

This solution is significantly simpler than the previous ones. It is stunningly obvious but I failed to see it. The syntax of `\chappdf`, `\chappdf*` and `\headerspdf` is unchanged. The command `\headerspdf` is also unchanged. But the code for `\chappdf` and `\chappdf*` is significantly simpler. (Actually, the code doing the work may be essentially identical. However, you no longer need to include it in your document.) This also avoids unnecessarily duplicating code from the standard class. Moreover, it is compatible with *some* customisation of chapter titles.

---

## Introduction

---

As I explain in the comments on the original question, it is really not going to be possible to provide a solution which fully meets the criteria since the requirement to adjust to arbitrary redefinitions of the page layout through the use of `titlesec` makes it impossible to know how much space is available for images on the first page of chapters. Even if it is known that `titlesec` is used, the package allows entirely free-form layout which again makes it impossible to calculate how much space remains on the page.

In addition, it is not possible to use `pdfpages` in a way which allows you to put the chapter title on the same page as pages included from PDFs if the `\chapter` command is to be issued separately from the call to `\includepdf` (without redefining `\chapter` in a way which would break other uses of the command).

Moreover, the differences in scaling etc. would make it much more complex to use a single command to include pages both on the first page of a chapter and on subsequent pages. So a separate solution is required for the start of chapters.

---

## Overview

---

This solution uses `pdfpages`. It provides two custom commands: `\chappdf` (plus a starred variant) and `\headerspdf`.

This solution will need to be adjusted if any of the following conditions hold:

- A chapter title runs to several lines for a chapter on which you want to include PDF pages on the first page of the chapter. [Definitely needs adjustment but you should be able to tweak the code, I think. Plus you should probably rethink your chapter titles if they are that long!]
- Either your document or the included PDF pages are not A4. [Possibly needs slight adjustment though I'm not sure. May be OK so long as size of included pages matches size of document. More likely to need adjustment if the two diverge, obviously.]

I have added `frame` to the options for the included PDFs just to show how things are laid out on the page. Obviously you can remove this option if you prefer. I've also adjusted the positioning of the included pages using `delta` (for spacing between the pages) and `offset` (for spacing around the block of pages). The latter is necessary to get the images properly centred with the default `twoside` option of `book.cls`. I used `geometry` with the `verbose` option to figure out the correct horizontal offset.

I've used `xparse` as it makes it easy to handle the starred and optional arguments. The definition of `\chappdf` and `\chappdf*` depend only on features of `xparse` considered stable.

The definition of `\headerspdf` depends on code from `xparse` marked as experimental. For this reason, should something break unexpectedly following an update, `\ProcessList` should be considered the prime suspect. I am not entirely clear about the status of `\SplitArgument` and `\SplitList`. On the one hand, they are not included in the list of commands deemed stable. On the other, they are not marked as experimental either.

---

## New Commands

---

Two basic commands are provided for the inclusion of pages from PDFs. (Obviously the usual commands provided by `pdfpages` remain available as well.)

### `\chappdf`

The solution uses a custom command, `\chappdf`, to include pages from a PDF on the first page of a chapter. **No more than 4 pages should be specified with this command.** If you wish to include further PDF pages, use `\headerspdf` to include them.

`\chappdf` is based on the definition of `\chapter`. Like that command, it accepts an optional short title for use in headers and table of contents. It also accepts a `*` if you do not want an entry in the ToC. Like `\chapter*` it is up to you to adjust the page headers as appropriate in that case. With the regular command, as with `\chapter`, this is automatic.

The syntax is as follows

```
\chappdf[short title]{chapter title}[page specification]{filename.pdf}
```

or

```
\chappdf*{chapter title}[page specification]{filename.pdf}
```

Both commands start a new page as if for a new chapter and set `chapter title` appropriately. If the second optional argument is not specified, `-` will be assumed and all pages from `filename.pdf` will be included. It is important the file not contain more than 4 pages in that case else the chapter will start over again on every new page. The syntax to specify the pages is identical to the value you would pass to the `pages` key using `pdfpages`. E.g. `1-2,4,89` or `2-5`.

### `\headerspdf`

`\headerspdf` is designed to include pages from a PDF in either 2x2 or 1x2 layout with the standard header and footer of the `fancy` pagestyle supported by `fancyhdr`. This means it is easy to redefine the headers and footers to your liking for the whole document and pages included with `\headerspdf` will respect your configuration.

`\headerspdf` can automatically adjust the layout for `nup=2x2` and `nup=1x2`. The code will automatically sequence the included pages correctly in the latter case e.g. by putting the first page at the bottom with the second page above so that they read left-to-right when orientated upright. If you would also like PDF viewers to automatically rotate these pages for readers, remove the `turn=false` option to `\includepdf` which suppresses this behaviour. (The rotation should not affect printing either way.)

```
\headerspdf[pdf inclusion options]{filename.pdf}
```

If no optional argument is provided, the default specifies inclusion of all pages in 2x2 format, along with other standard options. In the case that `nup=1x2` is specified, `\headerspdf` will also adjust the layout by requesting `\includepdf` to use `landscape=true`. As explained above, this avoids the need to specify the correct sequence of pages manually. You can say something like:

```
\headerspdf[pages=56-67,nup=1x2]{greatdoc.pdf}
```

or:

```
\headerspdf[nup=1x2]{fantasypdfs.pdf}
```

and the command should do the right thing. The latter will include all pages of the PDF in 1x2 format.

---

## Code

---

To make use of this solution, set up your document as follows:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{geometry}% optional
\usepackage{fancyhdr}% required (or change fancy to another pagestyle)
\usepackage{pdfpages}% required
\usepackage{xparse}% required

\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand\headerspdf{ O {pages=-,nup=2x2} m }{%
  \gdef\@myland{false}%
  \@splitpdfopts{#1}%
  \includepdf[%
    pages=-,
    nup=2x2,
    #1,
    delta=5pt 5pt,
    landscape=\@myland,
    turn=false,
    pagecommand={\thispagestyle{fancy}},
    scale=.65,
    frame,
    offset=-15pt 15pt]{#2}}
\NewDocumentCommand\@splitpdfopts{ >{\SplitList{,}}m }{%
  \ProcessList{#1}{\@splitpdfarg}}
\NewDocumentCommand\@splitpdfarg{ >{\SplitArgument{1}{=}}m }{%
  \@tweakpdfopts #1}
\newcommand\@tweakpdfopts[2]{%
  \def\tempa{nup}%
  \def\tempb{#1}%
  \def\tempc{1x2}%
  \def\tempd{#2}%
  \ifx\tempa\tempb
    \ifx\tempd\tempc
      \gdef\@myland{true}%
     \fi
  \fi}
\NewDocumentCommand\chappdf{somO{-}m}{% include all pages of PDF by default
  \cleardoublepage
  \includepdf[%
    pages={#4},
    pagecommand={%
      \IfBooleanTF{#1}{%
        \chapter*{#3}}{%
        \IfNoValueTF{#2}{%
          \chapter{#3}}{%
          \chapter[#2]{#3}}}},
    nup=2x2,
    scale=.5,
    frame,
    delta=5pt 5pt,
    offset=-15pt -45pt]%
    {#5}}
\makeatother

\pagestyle{fancy}% optional but probably what you want unless you change fancy in the definition of \headerspdf above

\begin{document}

% Document here as usual

\end{document}
```

---

## Example

---

`kantlipsum` is included to provide some filler text in the example, which also uses `mwe`'s documentation as a source PDF for the included pages.

### Code

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand\headerspdf{ O {pages=-,nup=2x2} m }{%
  \gdef\@myland{false}%
  \@splitpdfopts{#1}%
  \includepdf[%
    pages=-,
    nup=2x2,
    #1,
    delta=5pt 5pt,
    landscape=\@myland,
    turn=false,
    pagecommand={\thispagestyle{fancy}},
    scale=.65,
    frame,
    offset=-15pt 15pt]{#2}}
\NewDocumentCommand\@splitpdfopts{ >{\SplitList{,}}m }{%
  \ProcessList{#1}{\@splitpdfarg}}
\NewDocumentCommand\@splitpdfarg{ >{\SplitArgument{1}{=}}m }{%
  \@tweakpdfopts #1}
\newcommand\@tweakpdfopts[2]{%
  \def\tempa{nup}%
  \def\tempb{#1}%
  \def\tempc{1x2}%
  \def\tempd{#2}%
  \ifx\tempa\tempb
    \ifx\tempd\tempc
      \gdef\@myland{true}%
     \fi
  \fi}
\NewDocumentCommand\chappdf{somO{-}m}{% include all pages of PDF by default
  \cleardoublepage
  \includepdf[%
    pages={#4},
    pagecommand={%
      \IfBooleanTF{#1}{%
        \chapter*{#3}}{%
        \IfNoValueTF{#2}{%
          \chapter{#3}}{%
          \chapter[#2]{#3}}}},
    nup=2x2,
    scale=.5,
    frame,
    delta=5pt 5pt,
    offset=-15pt -45pt]%
    {#5}}
\makeatother

\pagestyle{fancy}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\tableofcontents

\chappdf*{2x2 PDF on Starred Chapter Page}[1-4]{/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/doc/latex/mwe/mwe.pdf}
  \kant[2]

\mainmatter

\chapter{Include 2x2 PDF after Chapter Page}
\kant[1]
\headerspdf[pages=1-8,nup=2x2]{/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/doc/latex/mwe/mwe.pdf}

\chappdf{2x2 PDF on Chapter Page}[1-4]{/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/doc/latex/mwe/mwe.pdf}
\kant[2]

\chappdf[Short Title]{2x2 PDF before 1x2 PDF}[1-4]{/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/doc/latex/mwe/mwe.pdf}
\kant[3]
\headerspdf[pages=1-4,nup=1x2]{/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/doc/latex/mwe/mwe.pdf}

\end{document}
```

### Output

[image: Example illustrating use of <code>\headerspdf</code>, <code>\chappdf</code> and <code>\chappdf*</code>]

---

## Styling Chapters

---

It is possible to redefine the standard `\chapter` and `\chapter*` commands to alter the layout of chapter titles. If you do this, be aware of the effect this will have on `\chappdf` and \chappdf*`. Two things are crucial:

1. The title must not consume more space than is allowed above the included PDF pages. You can alter this, if necessary, by editing the options passed to `\includepdf` by these commands.
2. The redefined command should not do anything too strange or it will break stuff when it is passed to the `pagecommand` option of `\includepdf`. The code must also be compatible with the use of `xparse`, including the experimental features this code invokes.

> **The injudicious use of `titlesec` or similar *will* break
>   stuff. This is expected.**

I ran several examples from `titlesec`'s documentation through and they all broke things badly.

That said, if you insist, it is possible to make **judicious** use of `titlesec`. If you try this and it breaks, you get to keep both pieces. I have personally never found something I could do with `titlesec` which I couldn't do more easily without `titlesec` or simply without. I therefore do **not** recommend using it with my code. I know my code is characteristically allergic to `titlesec`. ***Caveat emptor.***

---

## Dis-Recommended Example

---

Here is an example using `titlesec` which *does* work.

### Crucial Caveats

- `titlesec` is used for nothing especially exotic. It does not attempt
  to include pictures, play animations or exit with a musical flourish.
  It does not try to start new paragraphs, pages or crazes.
- In addition to introducing what I consider an unknown amount of
  volatility, this also looks dreadful. (I prefer not to encourage the
  use of a package I'm apparently allergic to.)
- ***Caveat emptor.***

About all I can say for this example, really, is that it compiles without error which is more than I can say for any of the other examples I tried (which, I hasten to add, were clearly not intended to be misused and abused in the way I attempted). ***Caveat emptor.***

### Code (Which I Do Not Recommend)

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{xparse}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Roman{chapter}}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\bfseries\large}{\MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename} \thechapter}{2ex}{\Huge}[\vspace{2ex}]

\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand\headerspdf{ O {pages=-,nup=2x2} m }{%
  \gdef\@myland{false}%
  \@splitpdfopts{#1}%
  \includepdf[%
    pages=-,
    nup=2x2,
    #1,
    delta=5pt 5pt,
    landscape=\@myland,
    turn=false,
    pagecommand={\thispagestyle{fancy}},
    scale=.65,
    frame,
    offset=-15pt 15pt]{#2}}
\NewDocumentCommand\@splitpdfopts{ >{\SplitList{,}}m }{%
  \ProcessList{#1}{\@splitpdfarg}}
\NewDocumentCommand\@splitpdfarg{ >{\SplitArgument{1}{=}}m }{%
  \@tweakpdfopts #1}
\newcommand\@tweakpdfopts[2]{%
  \def\tempa{nup}%
  \def\tempb{#1}%
  \def\tempc{1x2}%
  \def\tempd{#2}%
  \ifx\tempa\tempb
    \ifx\tempd\tempc
      \gdef\@myland{true}%
     \fi
  \fi}
\NewDocumentCommand\chappdf{somO{-}m}{% include all pages of PDF by default
  \cleardoublepage
  \includepdf[%
    pages={#4},
    pagecommand={%
      \IfBooleanTF{#1}{%
        \chapter*{#3}}{%
        \IfNoValueTF{#2}{%
          \chapter{#3}}{%
          \chapter[#2]{#3}}}},
    nup=2x2,
    scale=.5,
    frame,
    delta=5pt 5pt,
    offset=-15pt -45pt]%
    {#5}}
\makeatother

\pagestyle{fancy}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\tableofcontents

\chappdf*{2x2 PDF on Starred Chapter Page}[1-4]{/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/doc/latex/mwe/mwe.pdf}
  \kant[2]

\mainmatter

\chapter{Include 2x2 PDF after Chapter Page}
\kant[1]
\headerspdf[pages=1-8,nup=2x2]{/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/doc/latex/mwe/mwe.pdf}

\chappdf{2x2 PDF on Chapter Page}[1-4]{/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/doc/latex/mwe/mwe.pdf}
\kant[2]

\chappdf[Short Title]{2x2 PDF before 1x2 PDF}[1-4]{/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/doc/latex/mwe/mwe.pdf}
\kant[3]
\headerspdf[pages=1-4,nup=1x2]{/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/doc/latex/mwe/mwe.pdf}

\end{document}
```

### Output

[image: Do NOT try this at home!]

---

Comment: This works very nicely. However, `\chappdf*` still adds 'Chapter \thechapter' above the title. Can you tell me how to suppress that, as `\chapter*` only displays the chapter's title.

Comment: It's a bit odd. If I add a `*` after the first `\chappdf` in your code, It says: 'Chapter 1 \\ 2x2 PDF on Chapter Page', where it should just say '2x2 PDF on Chapter Page'. However, if I call it in my document it works fine...

Comment: @D.Roepo You are quite right. There was an error in my code. Please see my revised answer above. I'm not sure why it would have worked fine in your document. (It shouldn't!) Maybe you've redefined something else somewhere which counteracts the effect? Anyway, my testing suggests this now works as it should in the sense that it reflects the behaviour of `chapter*`. The page header needs to be adjusted just as it does for `\chapter*` but the erroneous 'Chapter...' before the title should be gone.

Comment: I was indeed changing secnumdepth to accidentally prevent \chappdf* from displaying 'Chapter \thechapter'. Now, as I do not fully understan the wrking of your solution: How do I keep all pages portait-oriented in my final document?

Comment: @D.Roepo Do you want them to print portrait-orientated? That should happen already. Or do you want them to appear that way in the viewer as well?

Comment: I meant in the viewer, the rest is perfect!

Comment: @D.Roepo See my updated answer. The `landscape=true` option (which is what means you don't have to specify the page sequence manually for 1x2) triggers automatic turning of pages in the viewer. `turn=false` blocks this. I've added this to the code and shown the difference in output when this option is removed (omitted as I had it originally) or included (new image).

Answer (score 4):

What is wrong with `\includegraphics` command?

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\begin{document}

\chapter{includepdf}
\centering
\fboxsep=0pt
\fbox{\includegraphics[page=1,width=.37\linewidth,height=.4\textheight,keepaspectratio]{pgfmanual}} \hfill
\fbox{\includegraphics[page=2,width=.37\linewidth,height=.4\textheight,keepaspectratio]{pgfmanual}}
\vfill
\fbox{\includegraphics[page=3,width=.37\linewidth,height=.4\textheight,keepaspectratio]{pgfmanual}}
\hfill
\fbox{\includegraphics[page=4,width=.37\linewidth,height=.4\textheight,keepaspectratio]{pgfmanual}}
\clearpage
\noindent
\fbox{\includegraphics[page=5,width=.48\linewidth,height=.45\textheight,keepaspectratio]{pgfmanual}}
\hfill
\fbox{\includegraphics[page=6,width=.48\linewidth,height=.45\textheight,keepaspectratio]{pgfmanual}}
\vfill
\fbox{\includegraphics[page=7,width=.48\linewidth,height=.45\textheight,keepaspectratio]{pgfmanual}}
\hfill
\fbox{\includegraphics[page=8,width=.48\linewidth,height=.45\textheight,keepaspectratio]{pgfmanual}}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The following should extract the first four pages of your pdf into pg_0001.pdf up to pg_0004.pdf:

```
pdftk A=numbered_pages.pdf cat A1-4 output new.pdf
pdftk new.pdf burst
```

Now you can use

```
\includegraphics{...}
```

in order to include these pdf files into your document individually. You can also use packages like TikZ on these graphics.

Comment: Alternative for `pdftk`: [PDF Split and Merge (PDFsam)](http://www.pdfsam.org/).

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun without PSTricks.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multido}
\def\filename{status-lua.pdf}
\def\scale{.1}
\pdfximage{\filename}
\begin{document}
\noindent\multido{\i=1+1}{\the\pdflastximagepages}{\fbox{\includegraphics[scale=\scale,page=\i,angle=90]{\filename}} }
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: As far as I know, `status-lua.pdf` is the only PDF file accessible for testing.

Comment: I don't understand this answer since none of the other answers use PSTricks either. And what do you mean that only status-lua.pdf is 'the only PDF file accessible for testing'? Also, it doesn't really seem to answer the question in any of the several forms it has taken.

Comment: @TheLastError: The package `mwe` has this name for reasons. ;-) See in `…/tex/latex/mwe`.

Comment: @cfr: Well, the answer by our user with the monthly changing name shows, that it is generally possible with `pstricks` …

Comment: @Speravir I'm obviously deeply confused about some basic aspect of reality. Or virtual reality, at least.