# Does \includepdf start a new page by default?

Tags: pdfpages

I'm using `pdfpages` package to insert some pages from a pdf file.

I'm using the following options within `\includepdf`

```
openright=false,%
frame=true,%
trim=3.5cm 2.8cm 3.5cm 5cm,%
clip,%
scale=.4,%
```

so that the frame is very small comparing with the text body. But the problem is that the page is being inserted in another page and so the section title is on a single page.

In other words, I'm doing this:

```
\newpage
\section{foo}\label{foo}
\includepdf[%
openright=false,%
frame=true,%
trim=3.5cm 2.8cm 3.5cm 5cm,%
clip,%
scale=.4,%
pages=1,%
pagecommand={},%
]{myfile}
```

but the output is (`showframe` only to prove that the box fits inside the text area)

[image]

I tried to check the `sty` file to see if there is some `\newpage` but no success.

Any idea how to avoid inserting new page?

Comment: Use `\includegraphics`. `\includepdf` is for pages.

Comment: `\includepdf[%
openright=false,%
frame=true,%
trim=3.5cm 2.8cm 3.5cm 5cm,%
clip,%
scale=.4,%
pages=1,%
pagecommand={\section{foo}\label{foo}},%
]{myfile}`

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, in fact, I'm using it for pages. But the 1st pages need a different trim.

Comment: You don't want the graphic to ocupy the whole page. So you are not including a page, you are including a graphic. So why not using `\includegraphics`? But the suggestion of touhami should work too.

Comment: Perhaps [my answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/160677/) might be helpful. It is for chapters but could be adapted for sections provided you are always starting a new page before the first section title/PDF i.e. it will only avoid page breaks *within* the set of {section heading, PDF pages added}. You still will get a page break before, if there is other stuff before the `\section`, and/or after, if there is other stuff after the final PDF page is added. [Harish Kumar's answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/160678/) shows how to use `\includegraphics`.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, is there `pages=` option for `\includegraphics`?

Comment: @touhami, your solution works fine but had to insert pages separately. Fisrt page only with your code and then the others. If you wish, you can post an answer.

Comment: You can insert one specific page with `page=X`.

Comment: @Sigur I think pages can only be inserted separately because of the different trim.

Comment: @touhami, I can not include all pages otherwise your code will be executed for each page and a lot of sections will be created.

Comment: @Sigur if no different trim or different scale you can do `pagecommand={\ifnum\value{page}=<page value>\section{foo}\label{foo}\fi}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pdfpages doc

> **pagecommand** Declares LATEX commands, which are executed on each sheet of paper. (Default: `pagecommand={\thispagestyle{empty}}`)

Here what we need is

```
\includepdf[%
openright=false,%
frame=true,%
trim=3.5cm 2.8cm 3.5cm 5cm,%
clip,%
scale=.4,%
pages=1,%
pagecommand={\section{foo}\label{foo}},%
]{myfile}
```