# Using pdfpages does not make the compiler print the title of the chapter

Tags: pdfpages

I have this code in my document

```
\chapter{Copyright Permission for Figure \ref{android:graph:layers}}\label{app:A}
    \includepdf[pages=-,nup=1x3,delta=0 -55]{figures/contentLicense.pdf}
```

But the output does not include the title of the chapter, it only outputs the the pdf pages that were included, but not the title.
If I add some text just under the chapter as:

```
\chapter{Copyright Permission for Figure \ref{android:graph:layers}}\label{app:A}
    Hello
    \includepdf[pages=-,nup=1x3,delta=0 -55]{figures/contentLicense.pdf}
```

Then it will output the chapter title followed by the text, but the included pdf will be in the next page by itself.

How do I make the title appear in the same page as the chapter title, without inserting any text in-between

Comment: This is the default behaviour of `\includepdf` - clear the existing page and insert the pages as-is. What you're asking is to overlay some content on the first included page? What if the overlaid content goes over top of the included page content?

Comment: Welcome! As @Werner says, `\includepdf` starts a new page by default. That much is usual behaviour. However, it is not usual behaviour for a preceding `\chapter{}` command to be entirely ignored. You need to show us the code in the form of a small compilable document which we can use to reproduce the behaviour.

Comment: Does [my answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/160646/include-multiple-pdf-pages-on-single-sheet/160677#160677) help? That answer provides a number of new commands for including PDF files on pages with chapter titles and/or headers. It tries to handle the spacing and so on in a sensible way i.e. the overlaid-content problem shouldn't occur. But it depends on using the new commands: it does not magically make `\chapter` or `\includepdf` do what they are not designed to do.

Comment: The other option, if your needs are less elaborate, is to use `\includegraphics` as shown by [Harish Kumar's answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/160678/) and also illustrated in [the question itself](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/160646/include-multiple-pdf-pages-on-single-sheet).